# Maxima tex() function without computing the equation?

Tags: tex-core, maxima

This may be simple but is there a way in Maxima to not compute an equation and output in Tex?

An example would be:

(%i1) tex(2^7 * 3^8 + sqrt(100));

$$839818$$

(%o1)                               false

but I would expect the result to look like

$$2^7 \times 3^8 + \sqrt{100}$$

If Maxima is not capable of this, I would be grateful if there are alternative libraries or Javascript codes to produce the same output.

Comment: Is this question about Maxima or is it about TeX?